# Delete a line if it contains N occurrences

Tags: search, replace

Is there a way to do a search and replace where it searches for if a line contains 4 pipes ( | ) anywhere in the line it will delete it?

I'm working with a big csv file and some lines have 4 pipes and some have 3 pipes. I want to separate out all the ones with 4 pipes in them into a separate file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regex-free one-liner which I like better than my previous answer.

```
:g/|/if count(getline('.'),'|')==4 | delete
```

On any line matching at least one pipe, then delete lines with exactly 4 pipes.

Comment: Doesn’t this need an endif?

Comment: That's what I thought initially.  It wouldn't hurt, but I found that it's not required.

Comment: cool thanks! works. but instead of deleting how do I separate it to the bottom of the file for editing manually?

Comment: `:g/|/if count(getline('.'),'|')==4 | move $`

Comment: Where do you find out all the different parameters such as delete move ....??? what is this g command called.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using:

```
:g/regex/d
```

There might be better regexes, but this one works.

```
:g/^[^|]*\(|[^|]*\)\{4}$/d

"   ^               - start of line
"   [^|]*           - non pipe characters
"  \(|[^|]*\)\{4}   - pipe followed by non-pipes exactly 4x
"   $               - end of line
```

If the file is very big, Vim might take too long to do this.  To speed it up, add space and underscore after the command to delete each match to the black hole register.

```
:g/regex/d _
```